# .NET Regex to Remove Square Brackets and @ sign inside it

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to get the attribute name in the XPath "root/customer/contact_number[@cellPhone]" so I could get "cellPhone".

I know how to get the entire "[@cellPhone]" string using "[@(.*?)]" as per [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%40%28.*%3F%29%5C%5D&i=root%2Fcustomer%2Fcontact_number%5B%40cellPhone%5D). I need the solution to be Regex as well.

Comment: How is the question too broad? Can you get any more specific with what's the regex to get 'cellPhone' from 'root/customer/contact_number[@cellPhone]'? Second paragraph only states what I've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=\[@)(.*?)(?=\])
```